# Iphone : Applying strechable images to a button disables it

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiimage

I am sure I am doing something stupid here.  I build a category on top of UIButton which I want it to take all of the background images assigned to it (different states) and convert them to stretchable versions and reapply them back to the button.

```
- (void)enableBackgroundImageStrechingWithLeftCapWidth:(float)leftCapWidth withTopCapHeight:(float)topCapHeight;
{

    UIImage *backgroundimageNormal = [self backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if (backgroundimageNormal != nil) 
    {
        UIImage *stretchImage = [backgroundimageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
        [self setBackgroundImage:stretchImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    UIImage *backgroundimageSelected = [self backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateSelected];

    if (backgroundimageSelected != nil) 
    {
        UIImage *stretchImage = [backgroundimageSelected stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
        [self setBackgroundImage:stretchImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }

    UIImage *backgroundimageHighlighted = [self backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    if (backgroundimageHighlighted != nil) 
    {
        UIImage *stretchImage = [backgroundimageHighlighted stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
        [self setBackgroundImage:stretchImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

    UIImage *backgroundimageDisabled = [self backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    if (backgroundimageDisabled != nil) 
    {
        UIImage *stretchImage = [backgroundimageDisabled stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:leftCapWidth topCapHeight:topCapHeight];
        [self setBackgroundImage:stretchImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
}
```

Seems to work except the button is now not clickable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the highlighted state causes the issue!

I have removed the highlighted block and it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have custom images for highlighted/disabled states, but rely on UIButton to apply the highlight/disabled effect, then `[self backgroundImageForState: UIControlStateHighlighted]` will NOT return `nil`. It will instead return a pointer to the normal state image.

Using your code, you are then effectively setting identical images for all states. They look like custom images to the framework, though. This disables the built-in highlight/disabled effects.